# Support smartphone devices only

Tags: android

I want my app be runnable only on smartphones, does not matter the density.
So I have few questions.
Should I use `<compatible-screens>` or `<supports-screens>`? What is the difference? Which tag will Google Play use to filter the app list?
Is this the correct way?

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="500"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

I have read different question about this argument but with different answers.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850115/difference-between-supports-screens-and-compatible-screens-on-android

Comment: Please post your full android manifest file. Only these parameters are not used for device filtering. Permissions/ uses feature tags also comes into filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use `<compatible-screens>` or `<supports-screens>`?

For your use case, `<compatible-screens>`, as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps).

> What is the difference?

For your use case, `<compatible-screens>` will work, and `<support-screens>` will not. `<supports-screens>` is only a filter for *smaller* sizes than you declare to support, not larger sizes.

> Which tag will Google Play use to filter the app list?

In general, both. For your use case, you can only express what you want via `<compatible-screens>`.

> Is this the correct way?

No, because you are missing a few densities (`tvdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `xxxhdpi`). Otherwise, that should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question, will my app be compatible with the Galaxy S5 given that it has a 5.2 inches screen and my app is not compatible with large screens?

Comment: @DanieleVitali: If Samsung declared their device as `-large`, you will not be available for that device. I do not have my S5 handy at the moment, so I cannot tell you what size bucket they chose.