# How to use <support-screens> and <compatible-screens> in android manifest?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I need to publish an android app on playstore. My app is meant for only tablets. Current manifest entry for supporting tablets is :

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

But with this configuration, my application was not visible on older **Nexus-7** tablets. So Now I've added compatible-screens label as well.

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>
```

Are these the only changes required to make my app visible on google playstore for Nexus 7 ?

And my other concern is whether it would be ok to use both support-screen and compatible-screen together in the manifest file. The link [difference between <supports-screens> and <compatible-screens> on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850115/difference-between-supports-screens-and-compatible-screens-on-android) explains it well. But its not mentioned whether both these labels can be used together.

EDIT :
    Permissions used by the app are :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the manifest code with uses-permission's.

Comment: Added uses-permission in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"But its not mentioned whether both these labels can be used together."**
Yes you can use both together in your manifest file.

As i had use same features for my application..!!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have used `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` in you manifest file.

If you have included camera permission for your application, Nexus 7 will be possibly listed as an UNSUPPORTED device because the Nexus 7 does have a front facing camera.

If this was the problem, to overcome this you can add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>` to your manifest file.

Comment: _@whit3hawks_ Can you please explain what this line does ?

Comment: The line is basically added to your manifest, to indicate that this feature is optional.

Comment: In my application I am using front camera. So, if this line is added I doubt front camera can be used. Although I will check that and let you know.