# Which compatible screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

Should I use:

```
  <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Or this:

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

I just want my app to show up on every screen. So, which one should I use? What is the difference anyway?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850115/difference-between-supports-screens-and-compatible-screens-on-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850115/difference-between-supports-screens-and-compatible-screens-on-android)

Comment: @MD Okay, so I found out the difference from that link, but if I don't have any compatible screens (which on default will be none) and I only have all supported screens, will my app be compatible with all? Thanks

Comment: @MD Okay, so then what is the point of having both supported and compatible? Which one should I have? What are the benefits of one or the other?