# Publish an Android App on Google Play only for smartphone

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, compatibility

For all day I've looked for a good way to pubblish an Android APp on Google Play Store for only smartphone.

I found this way http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps:

```
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="560" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

but the result was more strange.. 
the application appeared compatible with some device and some other not with no apparently sense.
For example:
The application was compatible with :
galaxy s6, galaxy s6 edge plus , google nexus 6 but not with samsung galaxy s6 edge .

What I have to do to obtain my goal to pubblish an app only for smartphone and not for tablet or minipc ?

P.s : is there a way to see the result of this manifest modification without re-pubblish the app every time ?

Comment: How do you define "smartphone?" Where do you draw the line with respect to screen size and screen density?

Comment: I don't want that my app runs on device over 6 inches in special way not all tablet 7,8,10 inches and mini pc :/ (Declaring an App is Only for Handsets)

Comment: it seems like thats the way to define the handsets, maybe the samsung s6 edge is an exculsive device that doesnt get that? checked on google s6 edge have 577 screen density, which exclude him.

Comment: I don't know.. maybe the only way is the @Columbo answer ?

Comment: try what I posted it should do the trick

Comment: I don't really understand the difference between compatible-screen and support-screen. I read this stackoverlow post http://stackoverflow.com/q/21850115/3681634 and I don't know if it is the right thing to do

Answer (score 2):

Edited :: Changed entire answer.

```
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="tvdpi" />


<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="tvdpi" />
```

so after clarifying the question precisely i figured you are missing this 6 lines of code to get all the densities for small and normal screen sizes.

let me know if that solve the Samsum S6 Edge issue.

Comment: Hi ! And thanks to the answer :) I have thought to use support-screens tag but I thought who that option when it is true ENables some android support conversion where the Android system mechanism who it zooms the app to adapt it to the device.. And this stackoverflow answer confIrm what I thought http://stackoverflow.com/q/21850115/3681634 . I didn't understand ?

Comment: well sadly on that question the wrong answer is marked if you look below it the right answer is applied. if a specific device exceeds the supported screens tag it wont be able to use your application.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english :/ however CoUld you explain when I have to use compatibility and when support-screen ? in the link that I have posted I understand that for my case the best solution was compatible-screen

Comment: For specifics my project is for only smartphone, moreover the layout is not optimized for tablet ;)

Comment: ok check what i wrote in the answer now, I'm pretty sure it should cover all handsets densities now

Comment: eh eh eh.. The problem is that this  android:screenDensity="xxdpi" ,"xxxhdpi" ,"tvdpi" are not supported.. infact I have put 480 for xxhdpi and 560 for xxxhdpi, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an entry like this in the manifest would pick the devices you want.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: and if the tablet have the telephony hardware ? :/